# Display specific layout when catching exceptions

Tags: android, exception, error-handling

What I'm trying to achieve is displaying a specific layout (only something that says that the app isn't working and maybe a button to kill it, on full page not a Dialog) when I'm catching a error in my Activity.

The only thing I'm able to do for know is catching an error and kill the app :

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread paramThread, Throwable paramThrowable) {
                Log.e("Kill app", "!!");
                // Here I would like to start something that displays a layout with my text
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
```

I really don't know how I should do that and if that's even possible.

Comment: When you say "specific layout" you mean a popup dialog? a full screen layout? Please elaborate.

Comment: I mean a full screen layout yes